# Lazy relationship initialization in service layer

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity with a OneToMany relationship lazy loaded.
I use Sping Data JPA to retrieve the entity, and in a method of my service I need to retrieve that list initialized, 'cause I need to print it in a JSP.
What I've done is:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public User retrieveUser(String username) {
    final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    user.getFriends().size(); //This line throws a LazyInitializationException
    return user;
}
```

But this solution doesn't work nor is elegant, how can I achieve it?

The exception is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.nikeconsulting.chirp.domain.User.follows, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:489)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:447)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:139)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:242)
at it.nikeconsulting.chirp.domain.service.ChirpUserServiceImpl.retrieveUser(ChirpUserServiceImpl.java:26)
```

My context.xml is:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="it.nikeconsulting.chirp.domain" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" id="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have a `context:component-scan` in both *servlet* and *root* application, and both initialize my **Service** but in the one of the *servlet* the transaction aren't initialized, so when the service was injected in the controller it use the one without the transactions management.

The solution was change the package in the `context:component-scan` for the *servlet* to let it scan just the controllers.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. I had the same problem. I was scanning for services in my MVCConfig file.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest fix is probably to make the collection eager. Ie:

```
class User {
....
  @OneToMany( ..., fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private Collection<Friend> friends;
...
}
```

Otherwise there are numerous reasons for this error:

- The service is not a Spring managed bean - therefor @Transactional on the method does nothing.
- If it is Spring managed bean, is the transaction manager configured properly ?
- If it is, the object might be detached. (Meaning navigating lazy associations won't work.) That happens when the find method it not transactional. You'll need to attach it first. It's something you can do by ... saving it (ie merge). I don't know if Spring Data has an attach method.

Comment: What I am doing is just an excercise so I would like to solve it in a properly manner. I don't know very much about JPA, so what can be the problem? I have my service declared as @Service an injected by Spring I have also declared the transactionManager but not sure if properly...what should I set to make it works? Some doc references?

Comment: Then I think your object is not attached. Use the save method to get an attached version of the object. Inside an @transactional method. That should do it.